# Dynamically column mapping

Tags: ssis

I have source data in 2 excel files. Data from both these excel files should be loaded to the same single Fact table. The column names in excel files and table are not same. I have a Reference table which has the column mappings between excel and Fact Table.
I have to refer this Reference Tabel for column mappings, plus i have to add some derived columns (Created_Date) to load the Fact_Table.

I have given a sample data structure below:

Source Data

```
Excel1_Order.xls
OrderNumber     OrderQuantity     OrderDate
Order10001      100        01-01-2011

Excel2_Customer.xls
CustomerNumber      CustomerName     CustomerAddress
Customer0001        CCPrivateLtd     India

ReferenceTable
Category      DestinationColumn        SourceColumn
Order         Disp_Col_1               OrderNumber
Order         Disp_Col_2               OrderQuantity
Order         Disp_Col_3               OrderDate
Customer      Disp_Col_1               CustomerNumber
Customer      Disp_Col_2               CustomerName 
Customer      Disp_Col_3               CustomerAddress

DestinationTable
Category        Disp_Col_1     Disp_Col_2     Disp_Col_3    Created_Date
Order           Order10001     100            01-01-2011    getdate()
Customer        Customer0001   CCPrivateLtd   India         getdate()
```

Is there any way to handle this in SSIS?

Comment: Am i correct, that the columns are always in the same order? So i.e. Excel1_Order.xls column one will always be in DestinationTable  Disp_col_1, column two will be in Disp_col_2, ..

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create two dataflows and let the filename determine which one to use.